# Should "Holler Nuff" be considered archaic?

Tags: word-usage

I faced this expression when I was reading The Adventures of Tom Sawyer. At first, it was easy to understand, because "Holler" and "Nuff" make sense in the context. However, I had some difficulty finding it on the web or dictionaries.

Comment: Both teams are present in dictionaries and are not considered archaic.  Holler https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT753IT753&hl=it&ei=uARZX82WBumV1fAPld-P8AE&q=holler+meaning+&oq=holler+meaning+&gs_lcp=ChNtb2JpbGUtZ3dzLXdpei1zZXJwEAMyBAgAEBMyBAgAEBMyBAgAEBMyBAgAEBMyBAgAEBMyBAgAEBMyBAgAEBMyBAgAEBM6BAgAEEc6AggpOggIABAWEB4QEzoFCAAQzQI6CggAEBYQChAeEBM6AggAOgYIABAWEB46AgguOgQIKRBGOgcIABBGEPkBUI4QWNgmYNEoaABwAngAgAFziAG5CJIBBDEyLjGYAQCgAQHAAQE&sclient=mobile-gws-wiz-serp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that it does not appear in a dictionary, is not enough to call a word or phrase "archaic".

I should imagine that the phrase is still used - it is very informal.

Holler nuff = Call out "Enough!" i.e. admit that you have been defeated.

OED

> **hollo | hollow | holla, v.**
>
> **Etymology:** Connected with holla int., hollo int.; also with hallo int. and hallow v.2
>
> **1.a. intransitive. To cry out loud, to shout, vociferate; to halloo.**
>
> 1642   T. Fuller Holy State ii. xix. 122   *'Tis madnesse to holloe in the ears of sleeping temptation.*
>
> 1919 Louisiana reports, Volume 143  *Mr. Sandlin was in his yard, in sight of us, and as we were going up by the side of the fence, he hollowed at us, and we stopped.*
>
> **holler, v.**
>
> **Etymology:** variant of hollo v. (dialect and U.S.)
>
> **To cry out loud, to shout; to complain. In a fight: to give up, to cry ‘enough’**
>
> 1926   J. Black You can't Win iv. 43   **Holler before you're hurt; that's my motto.**
>
> 1969   Times 22 July (Moon Report Suppl.) p. ii/3   **When Colonel Aldrin jumped off the last step of the moon ladder..everyone in the Aldrin home was whooping and hollering.**

Comment: When I was a boy, my stereotype of Americans was that they didn't holler "nuff", nor did they cry "uncle!". I mostly got this from Mark Twain and TV Westerns.